# How would I make program subtract the previous temp and current temp

Tags: c++, algorithm

An interactive C++ program whose input is a series of 12 temperatures from the user. It should write out on file tempdata.dat each temperature as well as the difference between the current temperature and the one preceding it. The difference is not output for the first temperature that is input. At the end of the program, the average temperature should be displayed for the user via cout.

Here is What I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int counter = 0;
    int previousTemp;
    ofstream file; //declares a file of type ofstream
    file.open("temperaturefile.txt"); //opens the file with open method
    int temperature = 0;
    int difference = 0;
    cout << "Enter 12 temperatutes" << endl;

    file << temperature;

    while (counter < 12)
    {

        cin >> temperature;
        counter++;
//        difference = temperature-previousTemp;
//        cout << difference << endl;
//
    }



}
```

Comment: And?  You haven't asked an actual question.

Comment: I updated the program. Sorry about that, Im still new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

You have it commented in your code? I don't understand

```
difference = temperature-previousTemp;
```

You can keep track of previousTemp at the end of your loop.
After everything in the loop put

```
previousTemp=temperature;
```